# How can I both Send and Receive from a Router socket in ZeroMQ or NetMQ?

Tags: c#, .net, zeromq, netmq

I have a Dealer <--> Router setup in *NetMQ v4* where I can asynchronously send and receive messages in any direction with no problems.

I now want to formalize that into an abstraction where the server (*Router*) listens for any incoming message but it also need to on demand broadcasts messages to any of the connected clients (*Dealers*).

I am trying to avoid using Pub <--> Sub sockets as I need the subscribers to also send messages to the server. The closest pattern to what I am trying to achieve is a WebSocket client-server communication.

The first part of listening to the client messages are done in something like:

```
using (var server = new RouterSocket("@tcp://*:80"))
{
    var addresses = new HashSet<string>();
    while (true)
    {
        var msg = server.ReceiveMultipartMessage();

        var address = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(msg[0].Buffer);
        var payload = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(msg[2].Buffer);
        Console.WriteLine("[Server] - Client: {0} Says: {1}", address, payload);

        var contains = addresses.Contains(address);
        if (!contains) { addresses.Add(address); }            

        msg.Clear();
        msg.Append(address);
        msg.AppendEmptyFrame();
        msg.Append("Reply for: " + address);
        server.SendMultipartMessage(msg);
    }
}
```

Now given that the sockets are not Thread-Safe, I am stuck on finding a way to broadcasts messages (coming from a different thread on demand) to all the clients.

I can probably use the `TryReceiveMultipartMessage` method in the loop instead with a set timeout after which I can check a queue for any broadcast messages and then loop through each client sending such message. Something like:

```
using (var server = new RouterSocket("@tcp://*:80"))
{
    var addresses = new HashSet<string>();

    var msg = new NetMQMessage();
    while (true)
    {
        var clientHasMsg = server.TryReceiveMultipartMessage(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), ref msg);
        if (!clientHasMsg)
        {
            // Check any incoming broacast then loop through all the clients
            // sending each the brodcast msg
            var broadMsg = new NetMQMessage();
            foreach (var item in addresses)
            {
                broadMsg.Append(item);
                broadMsg.AppendEmptyFrame();
                broadMsg.Append("This is a broadcast");
                server.SendMultipartMessage(broadMsg);
                broadMsg.Clear();
            }

            // Go back into the loop waiting for client messages
            continue;
        }

        var address = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(msg[0].Buffer);
        var payload = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(msg[2].Buffer);
        Console.WriteLine("[Server] - Client: {0} Says: {1}", address, payload);

        var contains = addresses.Contains(address);
        if (!contains) { addresses.Add(address); }

        msg.Clear();
        msg.Append(address);
        msg.AppendEmptyFrame();
        msg.Append("Reply for: " + address);
        server.SendMultipartMessage(msg);
    }
}
```

This somehow does not feel right mainly due to:

- What value for the timeout is a good value? 1 sec, 100 ms etc;
- Is this the most efficient/performing solution as this program will be used to have 100k+ clients connected with each sending thousands of messages per second.

Any pointers on what's the best approach to this is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use netmqqueue,  it multi producer single consumer queue. You can add it to NetMQPoller and enqueue from multiple threads without lock.

Comment: I was just reading your blog on `Device` and thought it would be a good choice until you mentioned the `Queue` :-) Have you got any examples somewhere (other than the few lines on http://netmq.readthedocs.io)?

Comment: Okay, I think I can get this working with no additional example just one more question, what's the difference between NetMQQueue<T> and the NetMQSscheduler? Is the scheduler obsolete in v4?

Comment: NetMQScheduler is obsolete (now part of NetMQPoller), anyway NetMQScheduler is queue of tasks, NetMQQueue is queue of any type.

Comment: The linked example shows a single dequeue per receive ready, but socket notifications (at least) are edge triggered.  Is this a problem?

Comment: The OPs Q is directly on point to minimal real world usage of 0MQ, but I can find no example of using a queue or second socket to pass outgoing messages to the single thread allowed to touch the original socket AND any blocking read (or hitting a send HWM) means you cannot shutdown because you cannot close the socket from another thread (or if you do it does not unblock).
So... can you provide a fuller example using NetMQPoller, a NetMQQueue, some "purposeful" socket, and a way to shut it all down?

Comment: The NetMQQeue is not edge triggered.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot find an example at the moment. You can check the unit tests of NetMQQueue:
https://github.com/zeromq/netmq/blob/e4234fc80527e17461673beba18d686aa31f0172/src/NetMQ.Tests/NetMQQueueTests.cs

Answer (score 0):

I think PUB/SUB is a proper approach for your requirements of 100k+ clients. Nevertheless, it doesn't mean that you can't communicate back to server: use DEALER/ROUTER. Why do you think this solution is not acceptable?

Comment: I am not sure I understand correctly. Are you saying that doing Pub/Sub using Dealer/Router based on my above solution looks reasonable to you?